# What's the difference between "non alcohol" and "alcohol free"?

Tags: meaning, differences, compounds

I saw a few groups on the web.

A group's name is "Non alcohol ~" and another one is "Alcohol free ~".

But I don't know the difference between "non alcohol" and "alcohol free".

I think that "non alcohol" and "alcohol free" have the same meaning.

Am I right?

Comment: I the context of "a group" these terms *may* have meanings peculiar to an organization such as Alcoholics Anonymous.  In the context of advertising the terms mean the same thing and whichever the ad men think will sell better is what would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They *kind of*  mean the same thing, but tend to be used differently

**Non-alcoholic** is commonly used when referring to beverages[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-alcoholic_beverage).

Additional, you *can* use **Alcohol free** can be used when referring to a trace amount of alcohol[2]

---

So which one you're using generally depends on the context.

Comment: As an addition to this, alcohol-free can also be used as an adjective to refer to someone who used to drink alcohol but no longer does: "I've been alcohol-free for four weeks now!" but non-alcoholic sounds awkward in the same place. (though I guess technically it would work because the person doesn't contain alcohol either. ;)) In that case, though, it would be far more fitting to use **teetotal** instead.